# require js and loading scripts time

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a question about loading scripts time via require.js. As i understand asynchronous loading is when all scripts loads independently and synchronous is when each script loads one by one. But i see the opposite picture:
without require.js like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/js/new/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/js/new/eventTrackerManager.v.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/js/new/constants.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/js/new/utils.js"></script>
...
```

[image]

And with require.js like:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "templates/js/new/",
    paths: {
        "jQuery": "lib/jquery-2.0.3.min",
        "jQueryUI" : "lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min",
        "Utils" : "modules/utils",
        "contactform" : "modules/contactform"
                ...
    },
    shim: {
        "jQueryUI": {
            exports: "$",
            deps: ['jQuery']
        }
    }
});
require(["contactform"], function(CF) {
    CF.init();
});
```

[image]

As u can see the the version without AMD is much faster. What did i do wrong?

Comment: when you mentioned `r.js`, do you mean the RequireJS optimization tool [r.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#download) or not?

Comment: In your first example with four consecutive `<script>` tags, a good browser will go fetch the .js file for each script all in parallel and will then execute them one after another in order.

Comment: @rhgb no, sorry i was little confused. Ofcourse i mean require.js

Comment: @jfriend00 but in the second example scripts loads one after another and then executing the same way. Does it mean that the first example better for performance?

Comment: please look at my answer below. require.js provide you better structure, and r.js provide you better performance.

Comment: @Kirill - I was just describing for you what a good browser does with regular `<script>` tags and why you see it look the way it does for the first case even though the scripts execute sequentially.  I don't exactly know how r.js works internally which is why I didn't comment on that case.  Just trying to help explain the parts I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMD itself doesn't make your js faster. it provides you better organization of code and avoid conflict of your js libs.

@jfriend00's comment explained why it is even slower after applying requirejs.

but, requirejs provided a optimization tool called [r.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html), which optimize your js code and actually make it faster by merging code snippets into larger js files.

see [WHY WEB MODULES?](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#download) for further information.